# Cannot login through Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, api, authentication

Here is the code of API calls and login through Facebook. 
The problem is that when it redirects to Facebook, it does not sign in.
What part of my code is wrong and how can I fix it?

```
require 'facebook/facebook.php';
require 'config/fbconfig.php';
require 'config/functions.php';
$url = $_REQUEST['lasturl'];

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId' => APP_ID,
          'secret' => APP_SECRET,
          'cookie' => true
    ));

$session = $facebook->getSession();

if (!empty($session)) {
    # Active session, let's try getting the user id (getUser()) and user info (api->('/me'))
try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $user = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (Exception $e) {


}

    if (!empty($user)) {
        # User info ok? Let's print it (Here we will be adding the login and registering routines)
       // echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($user);
       // echo '</pre><br/>';
        $username = $user['name'];
        $user = new User();
        $userdata = $user->checkUser($uid, 'facebook', $username);
        if(!empty($userdata)){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['id'] = $userdata['id'];
            $_SESSION['oauth_id'] = $uid;

            $_SESSION['username'] = $userdata['username'];
            $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = $userdata['oauth_provider'];
            header("Location: ".$url);
        }
    } else {
        # For testing purposes, if there was an error, let's kill the script
        die("There was an error.");
    }
} else {
    # There's no active session, let's generate one
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    header("Location: " . $login_url);
}
```

Comment: hope this link can solve your problem. thats a good and easy implemnt
http://25labs.com/tutorial-post-to-multiple-facebook-wall-or-timeline-in-one-go-using-graph-api-batch-request/

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code is fine and getting the login credential should work fine. But the problem is here.

```
if (!empty($user))
```

I think you should put this first before getting the user info with the API call. If the function getUser returns an ID then you don't need to get the current session just to get the user info.

Comment: please tell me exactly where should i put this "if (!empty($user))"?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code : `$session = $facebook->getSession();` don't work

```
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
       'appId' => APP_ID,
              'secret' => APP_SECRET,
              'cookie' => true
        ));

     $uid = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($uid) {
        # Active session, let's try getting the user id (getUser()) and user info (api->('/me'))
    try {

        $user = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (Exception $e) {


    }

        if ($uid) {
            # User info ok? Let's print it (Here we will be adding the login and registering routines)
           // echo '<pre>';
            //print_r($user);
           // echo '</pre><br/>';
            $username = $user['name'];
            $user = new User();
            $userdata = $user->checkUser($uid, 'facebook', $username);
            if(!empty($userdata)){
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['id'] = $userdata['id'];
                $_SESSION['oauth_id'] = $uid;

                $_SESSION['username'] = $userdata['username'];
                $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = $userdata['oauth_provider'];
                header("Location: ".$url);
            }
        } else {
            # For testing purposes, if there was an error, let's kill the script
            die("There was an error.");
        }
    } else {
        # There's no active session, let's generate one
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
        header("Location: " . $login_url);
    }
```